Why is rollup using `import('u'+'rl')` instead of just putting `import('url')` in the generated JS output?
I have an application that uses rollup to convert an ESM codebase to CJS before compiling it as a pkg.exe file. The issue with this is that pkg does not allow dynamic imports, which is fine by me as there is documentation for that. When I looked deeper into the issues, seems like it's caused by this line in the generated CJS file.
const dir = path.dirname(node_url.fileURLToPath((typeof document === 'undefined' ? require('u' + 'rl').pathToFileURL(__filename).href : (_documentCurrentScript && _documentCurrentScript.src || new URL('entry.js', document.baseURI).href))));

Why is rollup compiling it as require('u' + 'rl') instead of just using require('url')?

It's not really a blocker on my workflow as I can just use replace-in-file package to replace that back to 'url', but I'm curious as to why they did this in the first place. Performance maybe? Or something else?

maybe some fancy optimization of con strings https://github.com/danbev/learning-v8/blob/master/notes/string.md#consstring
